# How to apply QScrollerProperties to a QScroller, to get rid of overshoot?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, gesture

As the title says I'm trying to make a scrollArea that uses QScroller with grabgesture so I can scroll by dragging on the widget. I found some good examples and got it working. Now I want to remove the overshoot that happens when you drag further than there is items in the widget.
But when I try to tweak the Qscroller, I can't seem to figure out how to apply the QScrollerProperties to the QScroller. Which is how I assume you remove the overshoot.
Here is an example of the code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFormLayout,
    QGridLayout,
    QLabel,
    QScrollArea,
    QScroller,
    QScrollerProperties,
    QWidget,
)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(scroll_area)

        scroll_widget = QWidget()
        scroll_layout = QFormLayout(scroll_widget)

        for i in range(200):
            scroll_layout.addRow(QLabel('Label #{}'.format(i)))

        scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_widget)

        scroll = QScroller.scroller(scroll_area.viewport())
        scroll.grabGesture(scroll_area.viewport(), QScroller.LeftMouseButtonGesture)
        scroll.scrollerPropertiesChanged.connect(self.PropsChanged) #Just to see if I could registre a change

        props = scroll.scrollerProperties()
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.VerticalOvershootPolicy,QScrollerProperties.OvershootAlwaysOff)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.DragStartDistance, 0.01)

        #Apply Qscroller properties here somehow?
        print(scroll.scrollerProperties().scrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.DragStartDistance))
        scroll.scrollerProperties = props #Maybe? Doesn't seem to change the overshoot?


    def PropsChanged(self):
        print("Something is being changed??")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
Any help would be appriciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `scroll.setScrollerProperties(props)` once you've set the new properties.

When you call `scrollerProperties()` you get "copy" of the current properties: it is not a *pointer* to the actual properties, so nothing changes unless you apply them back to the scroller.

It's almost like calling `self.font()`:

```
    font = self.font()
    font.setPointSize(20)
    # at this point, the widget font is still the same...
    # unless you do this:
    self.setFont(font)
```

The same applies to almost any property, like `text()`/`setText()` for labels, `palette()`/`setPalette()`, etc.

To prevent the vertical overshoot, you have to use `setScrollMetric` with `VerticalOvershootPolicy`, and set the value to OvershootAlwaysOff:

```
    props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.VerticalOvershootPolicy, 
        QScrollerProperties.OvershootAlwaysOff)
    scroll.setScrollerProperties(props)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did solve my problem! I'm using pycharm as an editor, and for some reason it didn't show me that (setScrollerProperties) call on QScroller :)

Comment: @HumbleFumble You're welcome! I always prefer to study the class documentation, as it also allows one to find out more insight, and the comforts of IDE autocompletions can sometimes make us a bit lazier ;-)

Comment: Cheers, that seems like solid advice. 
Are you refering to the pyqt5 documentation or the Qt c++ doc? Because I seem to have trouble locating good docs on PyQt5, so any links would be super helpful.

Comment: I normally use the C++ docs, as they are usually consistent with PyQt, you only have to get used to the syntax. Consider that there are differencies: some function/signal overrides are not available on PyQt, while it provides some others that don't exist for C++; also, some C++ functions require an argument that is a pointer, which might not be included in PyQt *or* could be returned as an additional return value (like the some QFileDialog's statics, which return the path and the selected filter). For such cases, you can read [PyQt docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/).

Comment: What does overshooting means. The documentation doesn't explain what it is. I thought it would stop deceleration effect but it doesn't seem like it.